# Hide the already selected values in a QComboBox of a QtableView with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qcombobox

I have a table view with QComboBox widgets. All QComboBox have the same initial values, but once one value is selected, it has to be removed from the rest of QComboBox in the table. Is it possible?

I have a signal that when the text is changed in the QComboBox is saved in a set of used letters. So, I need to remove that letter from the rest of QComboBox in the table view.

My code below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class widgetTabContent(QWidget, Ui_widgetTabContent):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(widgetTabContent, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.QSModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.tvColumns.setModel(self.QSModel)
        self.letters = []

        self.cb_letters_used = set()
        self.fill_table()

    def combobox_current_text_changed(self, text):

        print(text)
        if text:
            self.cb_letters_used.add(text)
        print(self.cb_letters_used)
        # Commented this code as it becomes logically recursive

#        self.cb_update_list = [letter for letter in self.letters
#                            if letter not in self.cb_letters_used]
#        for row in range(self.QSModel.rowCount()):
#            self.tvColumns.indexWidget(self.tvColumns.model().index(row, 0)).clear()
#            self.tvColumns.indexWidget(self.tvColumns.model().index(row, 0)).addItems(self.cb_update_list)

    def fill_table(self):
         self.letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
         self.QSModel.setColumnCount(1)
         for row in range(len(self.col_letters)):
             combobox = QComboBox()
             combobox.add_items(self.col_letters)
             combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.combobox_current_text_changed)
             self.QSModel.insertRow(row)
             self.tvColumns.setIndexWidget(self.tvColumns.model().index(row, 0), combobox)
```

Comment: let's say that all the options have been selected as you indicate and the user wants to change the option, how would the user do it?

Comment: It may have a button to clear all the selected options and go back to the clean state.